# File does not exist while downloading Zip file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I'm getting error as the "file does not exist" as folder does exist.

> The file "../storage/app/public/bks/case_1/XsIbdGSJow7O3fhq9LyU.zip" does not exist

I have checked with Database field name `zipname` is not present but `job_id` is present. I'm not sure but do we have to have field name as `zipname` present in Database for this to download.

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
    {            
            @$job_id = $request->job_id;
            @$filenames = DB::table('analytics_report')->where('job_id',$job_id)->get()->pluck('filename')->toArray();
            @$zipname = $request->job_id;
            $zip = new \ZipArchive;
            $zip->open($zipname, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
            foreach ($filenames as $filename){
                $zip->addFile($filename);
            }
            $zip->close;
            @$path = '../storage/app/public/bks/case_1/'.$zipname;
            
            return response()->download($path);

     }

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo here `$zip->close;`. Should be `$zip->close()`;

Your code needs some checks before everything else.

```
public function downloadZip(Request $request)
{            
    if($request->has("job_id") === false) return;

    $job_id = $request->job_id;
    
    $filenames = DB::table('analytics_report')
                     ->where('job_id',$job_id)
                     ->get()
                     ->pluck('filename')
                     ->toArray();

    if (count($filenames) == 0) return;
    
    $zipname = $request->job_id;
    
    $zip = new \ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
    
    foreach ($filenames as $filename){
        $zip->addFile($filename);
    }
    
    $zip->close();
    
    $path = stprage_path('app/public/storage/bks/case_1/'.$zipname);
        
    return response()->download($path);

 }
```